# box shadows on multiple elements at same level but without overlap?

Tags: css, box-shadow, css-filters

I want to create something like the following screenshot, but I can't figure out any z-index value for which the shadow doesn't appear either over the first or second box (they are always stacked either with the first one on top, or the second).
[image: Overlapping boxes]

Is there a way to achieve the following?

[image: Desired - no overlap]

```
body { background: darkgrey; padding-top: 50px}
div { background: white; width: 200px; height: 200px; box-shadow: 0 0 20px 
black; margin: auto; position: relative; }
#box-one { left: -50px; z-index: 1; }
#box-two { right: -50px; z-index: 1; }
```

https://codepen.io/eoghanmurray/pen/oVEEVK

Comment: Do you have content filling to where the overlap is or could you cover it with something solid?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) and [`drop-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow) then you can apply a drop-shadow to the container. This shadow differs as it conforms to the alpha channel of the image (in this case, the outline of the content) instead of a simple rectangle:

```css
body {
  background: darkgrey;
  padding-top: 50px
}

#box-one,
#box-two {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#box-one {
  left: -50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box-two {
  right: -50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#top {
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 20px black);
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div id="box-one"></div>
  <div id="box-two"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a life / mind saver :D

Answer (score 3):

You can consider `drop-shadow` filter on a parent element:

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.b1,
.b2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
}

.b2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.container {
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 10px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
</div>
```

Or use an extra element to hide the overlapping shadows:

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}

.b1,
.b2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 13px #000;
  position: relative;
}

.b2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.b1:before,
.b2:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 15px;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}

.b2:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="b1"></div>
  <div class="b2"></div>
</div>
```

You can also build this using only one element:

```css
body {
  background: pink;
}
.container {
  width:250px;
  height:300px;
  background:
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top left,
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom right;
   background-size:150px 150px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 0 10px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, super answer; looks like @chazsolo's answer was just 2 minutes quicker

Answer (score 1):

I create a new `div` and set some `css` for it.

```css
body { background: darkgrey; padding-top: 50px}
div { background: white;  width: 200px; height: 200px; box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; margin: auto; position: relative; }
#box-one { left: -50px; }
#box-two { right: -50px;  }
#div1{
  position:absolute;
  background: white;
  width:100px;
  height:15px;
  margin-right:10px;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-top:185px;
  margin-left:199px;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1
 

}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="box-one"></div>
<div id="box-two"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner solution is to add the `box-shadow` to a pseudo-element like `::before` or `::after` and then add `position:relative` to a parent element.

```css
#box-one
{
  left: -50px;
}

#box-two
{
  right: -50px;
}

body
{
  background: darkgrey;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

.box-container
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.box
{
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.box::after
{
  content: "";
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div id="box-one" class="box"></div>
  <div id="box-two" class="box"></div>
</div>
```